# Is a dll created in Visual Studio 2005 supported in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2010 for C++ project. I need to use a dll and .lib file created in Visual Studio 2005. Is it possible?

Comment: What happens when you try to link against this DLL and the .lib in VS 2010 ? Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: Actually we have to make dll and .lib from a visual studio 2005 project, and after that we will use that in our visual studio 2010 project. Actually we want confirmation that it will work. can you help?

Comment: You will need to help yourself.  There's no guarantee that it will or will not work, it depends how clean the DLL interface is.  A simple C interface is rarely a problem, any std C++ classes in the exported functions are always a problem.  There's no point in asking this question if you *have* to use the VS2005 built DLL since you don't have any choice.  If you actually have the option to rebuild that DLL with VS2010 then *always* do that.

Answer (score 0):

Linking to a library from a different version of Visual Studio is usually fine. A few things to keep in mind:

1) The VS2005 libraries will target the VS2005 C++ runtime, so both the VS2005 and VS2010 redistributable packages would need to be installed on the end system.

2) Each runtime manages its own heap, so memory allocated by one runtime can't be safely deallocated by a different runtime. (Don't allow the executable to free memory allocated by the library.)